# Illegal invocation for a method assignation

Tags: javascript, dom

Why did i get an this kind of Error ?
Basically, I can short my code like this.

```
const log = console.log;
```

So why can't we have this one?

```
const _search = document.querySeletor;
```

Comment: You mean `querySelector`  ? and how much you will short your code by this `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: `document.querySelector.bind(document)`. Here `bind` will returns a reference to the `querySelector` function.

Comment: @CodeManiac I guess technically could be a sizeable number - a minifier will change that `log` to something like `a` so you'd save 10 characters for every `console.log`. On the other hand, it's hardly going to be significant - I suspect gzipping the minified file, even with `console.log` in it, will achieve the same or greater compression.

Comment: @VLAZ this what minifiers are built for, we can leave this part to those tools, also it will become hard on eyes to find which variable refer to which function,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelector` can be called on many things, not just the `document`, for example:

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('#outer');
const inner = outer.querySelector('div'); // querySelector called on `outer`
console.log(inner);
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

The `querySelector` method must have a root element from which to search from, which it identifies by the calling context of the function (the `this` value used inside it). In the above snippet, `outer.querySelector('div')` selects a `div` element which is a child of `outer`. Simiarly, with `document.querySelector`, you select a child *anywhere in the document* (but not, for example, in elements that exist, but are not attached to the document).

But without a calling context (eg, if you assign `querySelector` to a standalone variable), the method does not know what root element to search from, so it throws an error.

You *can* shorten it by `.bind`ing the function to the document first, so that it has the appropriate calling context when invoked:

```js
const qs = document.querySelector.bind(document);
console.log(qs('#inner'));
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `bind` method is what i was looking for, so thanks